# How to get to postgres database at localhost from Django in Docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I have a django in a docker container that must access a postgres database at my localhost. The Dockerfile works fine when accessing the database residing at an external host, but it can't find the database at my host.

It is a well known problem and there is a lot of documentation, but it doesn't work in my case. This question resembles [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) but it did not solve my problem. I actually describe the correct solution of this problem as @Zeitounator pointed out, but it still did not work. It was thanks @Zeitounator that I realised two parts of the problem must be solved: the docker side and the PostgreSQL side. I did not find that solution in any of the answers I read. I *did* however read about the same frustration: getting a solution that did not work.

It all focuses on which internet address I transmit to the `HOST` key in the database driver dictionary in the django settings.py:

```
print('***', os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'], os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST'], os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT'])

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # os.environ['ENGINE'],
        'NAME': 'demo',
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST'],
    }
}
```

And running the Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t dd .
docker run --name demo -p 8000:8000 --rm dd
```

When POSTGRES_HOST points to my external server 192.168.178.100 it works great. When running `python manage.py runserver` it finds the host and the database. The server starts and waits for commands. When pointing to 127.0.0.1 it fails (which actually is great too: the container really isolates).

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But as I can connect to my server, I should be able to connect to the localhost IP and that fails just as well (I forgot to tell that the database really runs). When I use `host.docker.internal` it doesn't work either when running:

```
docker run --name demo -p 8000:8000 --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway dd
```

It replaces `host.docker.internal` by 172.17.0.1. The only solution that works so far is:

```
# set POSTGRES_HOST at 127.0.0.1
docker run --name demo -p 8000:8000 --rm --network host dd
```

but that seems something I don't want. As far as I understand the documentation it makes the full host stack available to the container which defeats the idea of a container in the first place. But second: it doesn't work in `docker-compose`, though I specify:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

`network_mode: host` leads to a compile error, docker-compose refuses to run.

Is there a way to access a service running on my PC from a docker running on my PC as well from Dockerfile as well as docker-compose and can be deployed as well?

using Ubuntu 21.04 (latest version), Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5.1, postgresql v14. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Comment: `host-gateway` used in your `add_host` stanza will make `host.docker.internal` point to your default docker bridge in both plain command line docker and compose (i.e. `172.17.0.1` in your setup). There is absolutely no reason why you could not contact your postgres server on that IP **as long as your local postgres server is listening on that interface and allowing connections to your server/db from it**

Comment: From the point of view of your Django container, 127.0.0.1 is a Django container that isn't running a database; every program on every computer is "running on localhost" but it's a different localhost.  You should be able to configure `POSTGRES_HOST=host.docker.internal` (with the `--add-host` option you show on native Linux).  Also consider running the local database in a container so you can use native Docker networking and have per-project database servers.

Comment: @David, I had already tried what you suggested and it resolved to 172.17.0.1, an address I already found in ifconfig. Sorry I was not clear about that in my question. You are absolutely right about containerizing the database part as well, but if I am not able to solve the problem of accessing my localhost database it's clear that I don't understand the problem very well. That's why I wanted to solve that first. I will now start to do as you suggest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts in solving this problem: the docker part and the postgresql part as @Zeitounator pointed out. I was not aware of the postgres part. Thanks to his comment I could resolve this issue. And it works for Dockerfile as well as docker-compose where this Dockerfile is used.

One has to change two postgres configuration files, both are on /etc/postgresql/<version>/main:

**postgresql.conf**

Change the listen address. Initially it shows:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
```

I changed 'localhost' to '*'. It can be more specific, in this case to the docker address, but as a Proof of Concept it worked.

**pg_hba.conf**

In my case `host.docker.internal` resolves to 172.17.0.1. This seems some default docker gateway address as I noticed in most discussion regarding this subject.
Add two lines at the very end of the file:

```
host    all             all              172.17.0.1/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::ffff:ac11:1/0                            md5
```