# Connecting a Docker-ized Django app to local Postgresql database

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

For deployment purposes, I have set up my Django app in a Docker container. The setup works, and I am able to serve it using Gunicorn and Apache. However, I can't seem to access my Postgresql database anymore. This database is running locally, and I have no problem accessing it when launching my Django app from outside the container.

But when I launch my app from inside the Docker container, all I get is this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5433 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Clearly I am not the first one having trouble with this.

I have made sure that Postgresql is listening to external adresses, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099061/how-to-get-to-postgres-database-at-localhost-from-django-in-docker-container), so this shouldn't be a problem.

I have also tried playing around with my Docker compose configuration file. Using `network_mode=host` is not compatible with port bindings. Back in `network_mode=bridge`, I have also tried as upvoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) :

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

But it does not change anything, nor does replacing `127.0.0.1` with `172.17.0.0` in my Django .env file.
I am a bit at a loss here, so any insight would be appreciated. I have to say that I am new to Docker, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04, Docker 24.0, Django 4.2, Postgresql 14. Here is my really simple docker-compose.yml :

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./main/.env
```

And a sample .env file :

```
DATABASE_NAME=db_name
DATABASE_USER=db_user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=port
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path by adding the extra hosts.

Point the DB to the host gateway config to make it work, you are still not in localhost.

```
DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Make sure to stop/restart docker compose so the env variable change will take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately it still does not work. The `OperationalError` appears again, except that `"127.0.0.1"` is now replaced by `"host.docker.internal" (172.17.0.1)`

Comment: You will have to configure postgres to accept connections.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database

Comment: I have made this configuration already

Comment: @chatours - Are you able to connect to your DB from within container using psql client?  It may help isolate where is the problem.

Comment: psql command is not found when I open a terminal from within container. Sounds good to me, since I didn't install it in the container

Comment: try to see postgresql logs to understand what's going on

`tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log`

Comment: And try to update your postgresql configuration like here https://gist.github.com/MauricioMoraes/87d76577babd4e084cba70f63c04b07d

Comment: My mistake, a `#` was polluting my `postgresql.conf`. Removing that led to Postgresql actually listening to other addresses, and your solution now works. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Login to your container with `docker exec -it` and run `hostname -I` command and get the ip. Then in your localhost run command `hostname -I`. You should have an ip in a network with your container. Replace that in `DATABASE_HOST` in your env file.

Also you can define bridge network in your compose file to be in a same network with your localhost.

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./main/.env
    network_mode: bridge
```

Now you can put your localhost ip instead of `DATABASE_HOST`. And for your `Out of memory` probelm , this [link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) might help.

Comment: It helped, `hostname -I` returns 172.22.0.1 and not 172.17.0.1 as I expected. Could you explain why? I don't get an `OperationalError` anymore. Things seem to load for a while, then I get this error: `[ERROR] Worker (pid:19) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?` Any ideas?

Comment: That might not be the best way as there is no guarantee of IPs changes after a restart of your system or docker.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it helps !